# Python script for finding keith numbers not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, numbers

I am trying to make a python program that will find keith numbers. If you don't what keith numbers are, here is a link explaining them:
[Keith Numbers - Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KeithNumber.html)

My code is

```
from decimal import Decimal
from time import sleep

activator1 = 1

while (activator1 == 1):
    try:
        limit = int(raw_input("How many digits do you want me to stop at?"))
        activator1 = 0
    except ValueError:
        print "You did not enter an integer"


limitlist = []
activator2 = 1

while (activator2 <= limit):
    limitlist.append(activator2)
    activator2 += 1
    print limitlist

add1 = 0
add = 0
count = 9
while 1:
    sleep (0.1)


    numbers = list(str(count))

    for i in limitlist:
        if (i > 0) & (add < count):
            add = sum(Decimal(i) for i in numbers)
            lastnumber = int(numbers[-1])
            add1 = lastnumber+int(add)
            numbers.reverse()
            numbers.pop()
            numbers.append(add1)
            print add1
            print add
            print count
            print numbers
        if (add1 == count):
            print"________________________________"
            print add1
            print count

        elif (i > 0) & (add > count):
            count += 1
            break
```

It doesn't output any errors but it just outputs

```
18
9
9
[18]
```

Could someone please tell me why it doesn't just repeatedly find Keith numbers within the number of integers range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prune has already given you good advices! Let's put a little example of what he meant though, let's say you got an algorithm which determine whether n is a keith number or not and also a test loop to print some keith numbers:

```
def keith_number(n):
    c = str(n)
    a = list(map(int, c))
    b = sum(a)

    while b < n:
        a = a[1:] + [b]
        b = sum(a)

    return (b == n) & (len(c) > 1)

N = 5
for i in range(N):
    a, b = 10**i, 10**(i + 1)
    print("[{0},{1}]".format(a, b))
    print([i for i in filter(keith_number, range(a, b))])
    print('-' * 80)
```

such snippet gives you this:

```
[1,10]
[]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[10,100]
[14, 19, 28, 47, 61, 75]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[100,1000]
[197, 742]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1000,10000]
[1104, 1537, 2208, 2580, 3684, 4788, 7385, 7647, 7909]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[10000,100000]
[31331, 34285, 34348, 55604, 62662, 86935, 93993]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Wow, that's awesome... but wait, let's say you don't understand the keith_number function and you want to explore a little bit the algorithm in order to understand its guts. What about if we add some useful debug lines?

```
def keith_number(n):
    c = str(n)
    a = list(map(int, c))
    b = sum(a)
    print("{0} = {1}".format("+".join(map(str, a)), b))

    while b < n:
        a = a[1:] + [b]
        b = sum(a)
        print("{0} = {1}".format("+".join(map(str, a)), b))

    return (b == n) & (len(c) > 1)

keith_number(14)
print '-' * 80
keith_number(15)
```

that way you'll be able to trace the important steps and the algorithm will make sense in your head:

```
1+4 = 5
4+5 = 9
5+9 = 14
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1+5 = 6
5+6 = 11
6+11 = 17
```

Conclusion: I'd advice you learn how to debug your own code instead asking strangers about it ;-)

Comment: Thats awesome, I'll work more on debugging and I'll start the program again so I have a clear idea of what is going on

Comment: @renzen Yeah, that's a good attitude! You'll realize very soon solving these kind of problems by yourself is much more rewarding than others giving you the solution. Good question though, I didn't know keith numbers till now :D

Answer (score 4):

You have it in front of you:

```
add1  = 18
add   = 9
count = 9
numbers = [18]
```

You're in an infinite loop with no output.  You get this for *once*.  After this, **i** runs through the values 1, 2, and 3.  Each time through the **for** loop, all three **if** conditions are **False**.  Nothing changes, you drop out of the **for** loop, and go back to the top of the **while**.  Here, you set **numbers** back to ['9'], and loop forever.

I suggest that you learn two skills:

1. Basic debugging: learn to single-step through a debugger, looking at variable values.  Alternately, learn to trace your logic on paper and stick in meaningful **print** statements.  (My version of this is at the bottom of this answer.)
2. Incremental programming:  Write a few lines of code and get them working.  *After* you have them *working* (test with various input values and results printed), continue to write a few more.  In this case, you wrote a large block of code, and then could not see the error in roughly 50 lines.  If you code incrementally, you'll often be able to isolate the problem to your most recent 3-5 lines.

---

```
while True:
    # sleep (0.1)

    numbers = list(str(count))
    print "Top of while; numbers=", numbers

    for i in limitlist:
        print "Top of for; i =", i, "\tadd =", add, "\tcount =", count, "\tadll =", add1
        if (i > 0) & (add < count):
            add = sum(Decimal(i) for i in numbers)
            lastnumber = int(numbers[-1])
            add1 = lastnumber+int(add)
            numbers.reverse()
            numbers.pop()
            numbers.append(add1)
            print "add1\t", add1
            print "add\t", add
            print "count\t", count
            print "numbers", numbers
        if (add1 == count):
            print"________________________________"
            print add1
            print count

        elif (i > 0) & (add > count):
            count += 1
            print "increment count:", count
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem , and also I'm actually new here , so basically I solved it with the use of lists I hope u can understand :)

```
def kieth(n):
    n1 = n[::-1]
    f = [0]
    [f.insert(0, int(x)) for x in n1]
    for x in range(1, int(n)):
        if f[-2] == int(n):
            break
        else:
            f.insert(-1, sum(f[-abs(len(n1)) - 1:-1]))
    return True if int(n) in f else False

n = input(" enter a number ")
print("is a kieth number " if kieth(str(n)) else "not a keith")
```